# Google Autocomplete Polygon as GeoJson

Tags: google-maps, polygon, geojson, nominatim, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I'm trying to find in the Google Maps documentation a way to search for a place and get it's GeoJson polygon but I got no luck finding something like that.

My goal is to create a search bar to search places and then send the geojson polygon to our back-end. I don't want to draw it on a map or anything front-related.

Nominatim is doing exactly [what I want](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=france&format=json&polygon_geojson=1) but [Nominatim policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Usage_Policy) is very restricted so before I go for an [alternative](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers), I wanted to check if Google Maps could provide the same (especially since searching for a country on Google Maps retrieve the polygon and draw it on the map).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Google Maps APIs don't expose any polygons data of geographic features. You can see very old feature request in the Google issue tracker to add this functionality, however it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953

Feel free to star the public feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further updates from Google.

You should get polygons from other sources.